# How to print only one segment from column .csv python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a column that looks like this:

```
19E071OE1 [OO 2019] P1
```

I want to print out only the part in [] so the output is like:

```
OO 2019
```

Comment: Does your column always look like that? Is it in a string? If so, the simplest way is to split along a delimiter (`[`, then `]`) twice and keep the inner piece.

Comment: @anvoice no it changes but the positions stay the same and the number of characters

Comment: Then the answer by @marcdtheking is what you want.

Comment: Are these the columns or the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(('19E071OE1 [OO 2019] P1').split('[')[1].split(']')[0])
```